# iPhone5 Images not loading

Tags: xcode4.5

I have developed an app in Xcode of type Universal . When I run the program it is displaying the Images properly in iPhone5 4 inch simulator. But on my device the Images are not loading.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()  == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale >= 1136)
{        
    image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lifestyle12_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lifestyle11_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lifestyle10_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lifestyle2_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LifeStyle1_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lifestyle5_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image7.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"APP_incipio_F38_iPhone5@2x.png"];
    image8.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"APP_incipio_BACKPACK_iPhone5@2x.png"];
}
```

Kindly tell me the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your carefully checked the file names? The device has a case sensitive file system